# Windows Phone 7.5 WebApp metadata

Tags: web-applications, windows-phone-7

Just like in iOS and Android we can set some metadata for the `viewport` and specially the application icons, **what is** the metadata on a webapp to show an icon when bookmarking it to the dashboard?

And what more can I append as a `<meta>` tag to make the web app more "nativish"?

Can't find many info about that, honestly, I find almost nothing when it come to web apps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way of specifying a more native feel.
The phone doesn't use icons when bookmarked/favourited. The nearest equivalent thing is the screenshot that is used when the site/page is pinned to the users start screen.

If you want to control/improve the image that is used when the user pins a site/page, you could try what goolge do. They encoourage users to visit a specifically formatted page and then pin that. (Go to google.com on a phone to see it in action.)

This is different to what iOS and Android do as WP tries to more clearly distinguish between apps and sites, whereas for iOS at least they almost want the user to be unable to distinguish between them.